# How to interpret the inside of a .svg vector image

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I'm curious as to the specifics of how vector images (specifically .svg) work.

When I open a .svg vector image in notepad, I can see the XML data that makes up the image (I put an example [here](http://pastebin.com/jtFw0u49) for quick reference).

I understand that the first few tags are metadata, and that the following  tags each correspond to different lines, but I don't understand what the class, d, and transform elements within each  tag actually mean, and how they describe a line.

Comment: Disregard the class and transform, the meat is in th `d` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  No matter how much I searched I could only find high-level descriptions of how vector images work.  If you post this as an answer I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `d` attribute of SVG `<path />` element contains instructions to draw the line. I think it's the most complex attribute in SVG, but MDN explains it in  quite an accessible article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d In a nutshell it tells the interpreter to connect points `x0,y0`, `x1,y1`, `x2,y2` ... etc using a line/curve/arc or just jump from one point to the nest.

Many shapes can be defined using much [simpler constructs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element#Basic_shapes) - simple enough to be written by hand or interpreted by just looking at the source code: like `<line />`, `<rect />`, `<circle />` or `<polyline />`.

The `transform` attribute changes the position/size/rotation of an element without the need to re-calculate every point in the source code, and `class` is used for styling purposes so you can define the looks (color, line thickness, fill) independent from the shape definition.